# how to Deserialization json response type of without using library swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, tuples, alamofire

I have create this login function to get user anthnication and allow him to lign to the app. I have one problem with how can I Deserialization tuples of [String : AnyObject] without example  let user:String = resp.1 as! String

```
func getUserCredential(username:String,password:String)->UserModel
     {
        var authenticatedUser  = UserModel()
        let user = username
        let password = password

        let credential = NSURLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .ForSession)

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
            .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print("response \(response)");
                if let validResponse = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                {
                    for resp  in validResponse
                    {
                        let user:String = resp.1 as! String
                        let isAuthenticated:Bool =  resp.0 as! Bool
                        let isManager:Bool = true
                        authenticatedUser = UserModel(username:user,isAuthenticated:isAuthenticated,isManager:isManager)
                    }
                }
                else if let error = response.result.error
                {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
        }
        return authenticatedUser;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out

```
func getUserCredential(username:String,password:String)->UserModel
        {
            var authenticatedUser  = UserModel()
            let user = username
            let password = password

            let credential = NSURLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .ForSession)

            Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
                .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .Success(let JSON):
                        print("JSON :\(JSON)");
                        let responseJson = JSON as! NSDictionary
                        let username:String = responseJson.objectForKey("user")! as! String
                        let authenticated:Bool = responseJson.objectForKey("authenticated")! as! Bool

                        authenticatedUser = UserModel(username: username,password:password,isAuthenticated: authenticated,isManager:false)

                    case .Failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
            }

            return authenticatedUser;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is using a library, AlamoFire.

Alamofire has JSON support built into it. Just use the JSON functions it has.

If you want to convert JSON data back into objects without using a third party library then use `NSJSONSerialization`. The method 'JSONObjectWithData:options:error:' will take JSON data as input and return deserialized objects from that data.

### Edit:

You said "...how can I Deserialization tuples of [String : AnyObject] without example let user:String = resp.1 as! String".

I have no idea what that means. `[String:AnyObject]` is a dictionary, not a tuple.